# Mongoose: tried to set nested object field to primitive value 'null'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema with nested fields e.g.

```
// model.js
module.exports = Mongoose.model('Model', new Mongoose.Schema(
    {
        Top: {
            Middle: {
                Bottom: Number
            }
        }
    },
    {
        strict: 'throw'
    })
)
```

It is quite rare that all these fields exist, and when a field doesn't exist, the process generating it writes `null`. I would like to have strict mode set to `true` but it doesn't seem to like when a field that should contain an Object instead contains `null`:

```
// app.js
const Model = require('./model');
router.post('/api' , async (req, res) => {
    const doc = new Model(req.body);
    const result = await doc.save();
    res.json(result);
})

// test
axios.post('/api', { Top: { Middle: null }})
=> ObjectExpectedError: Tried to set nested object field 'Middle' to primitive value 'null' and strict mode is set to throw.
```

Is there any way to circumvent this behaviour? Unfortunately it is not a trivial option to have the process generating the data produce `undefined` instead of `null`.

Comment: please share your insert/update code

Comment: you can set {} instead of null

Comment: added some code to show basic express endpoint, hopefully that's what you were after

Comment: Can you share your model.js code?